# How to print meta property using custom meta tag module

Tags: meta-tags

I have implemented the custom meta tag module found here:
http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/creating-custom-meta-tags-with-the-metatag-module/

The following code creates my new meta tag, the problem is that it creates a

```
<meta name="my_custom_metatag">
```

tag.

How can I make it print out a

```
<meta property="my_custom_metatag">
```

tag instead?

```
<?php
//
// Implements hook_metatag_info().
//
function my_metatags_metatag_info() {
  $info['groups']['my_metatags'] = array(
    'label' => t('My Custom Metatags'),
  );

  $info['tags']['my_custom_metatag'] = array(
    'label' => t('My Custom Meta Tag'),
    'description' => t('This is a custom meta tag'),
    'class' => 'DrupalTextMetaTag',
    'group' => 'my_metatags',
  );

  return $info;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telling your custom meta tag to use the property theme formatter should do the trick.

```
$info['tags']['my_custom_metatag'] = array(
  'label' => t('My Custom Meta Tag'),
  'description' => t('This is a custom meta tag'),
  'class' => 'DrupalTextMetaTag',
  'group' => 'my_metatags',
  'element' => array(
    '#theme' => 'metatag_property',
  ),
);
```